# Multiple custom Svelte stores in one single file

Tags: svelte

I need to have multiples svelte store in one single JS file. But the current syntax doesn't easily allow me to do so.

```
var store1
const {subscribe, set, update} = writable(store1)
export const Store1 = {
    subscribe,
    function1:function1(),
    function2:function2()
}

var store2
const {subscribe, set, update} = writable(store2)
export const Store2 = {
   subscribe,
   function3:function3(),
   function4:function4()
}
```

The problem is I have two "subscribe", "set" and "update" declared because of this line :

```
const {subscribe, set, update} = writable()
```

But I can't give them a different name because they don't exist in "writable".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either not destructure the object returned by `writable` or assign to new variable names: i.e.

#### Assign to variable

```js
const store2writable = writable();
store2writable.subscribe(...);
```

#### Assigning to new variable names

```js
const { subscribe: secondSubscribe, set: secondSet, update: secondUpdate } = writable();
secondSubscribe(...);
```